# How can I get the count of line in a file in an efficient way in Dart?

Tags: dart

How do I read count of lines in txt file?
I have known that i have to use `ByteBuffer` but i dunno how use it.
Is there a `scanf` in Dart?

Comment: Even in C, you should never use `scanf`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myFile = new File('file.txt');
// assuming a utf8 encoding
var numberOfLines = myFile.readAsLinesSync().length;
```

See [readAsLinesSync](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-io/File/readAsLinesSync.html) doc to provide an other encoding.

Answer (score 1):

```
final file = File('file-name.ext');
// assuming utf8
final numberOfLines = await file.readAsLines().length;
// or synchronously
final numberOfLines = file.readAsLinesSync().length;
```